# Why NPN Transistor AND Gate not working?

Tags: transistors, npn

I am trying to form an AND Gate using 2 NPN Transistors, But the led lights up when i turn on the right switch and the left switch doesn't make any change, Can Someone please point out the problem,

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please draw a proper schematic and state how your circuit is not working - what do you expect and what happens instead.

Comment: The problem is that NPN transistors connected like that do not form an AND gate, and with no resistors it will blow up the transistors and LED. What do know about AND gates, NPN transistors, and LEDs to know from where to start explaining why it does not work?

Comment: there is no `left led` or `right led`

Comment: @jsotola sorry, I meant Switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve: [falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAXcYlb3lFDT5RwUaIUx4wuMBjyFsGIsTEZIGCUsIIENPJF3IqAEwYAzAIYBXADYdOwlAkIgBQpy6oQYajZiI6egZCPtgIONgoxJDYhGBSkUYgppa29gDuroKu%20FnuNFSQbADmea5KZSh4eCJFAM6OzuA07k2FIJY2dQxsDWA8wmAtwu2d3WxgEmWE7tms-Mnm1nZMNgzGou0wkOwATmXzBxoiYHBsAErTs0KJ7QUgKlvQCGz7Q0L9vO8gMydnmd9fm4fiE2ADhh5mh8BkUgA)

Edit: A Tinkercad simulation showing the same circuit can be found [here](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/iETIg5v1S6E-mighty-curcan-jaagub/editel?sharecode=lcjcD7BOPJiM8EahqR6YlJryYgVC2l9KGYVVRo5GjM0).

The discussions in the comments are follow-ups on OP's question and go into how to design your own CPU like Ben Eater's 8-bit CPU from TTL ICs (which is how I learned about what really happens on a very low level) and the downsides of using TTL vs CMOS:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyznrdDSSGM&list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU

Other great resources for learning CPU design are [NandGame](https://nandgame.com/) and [Turing Complete](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1444480/Turing_Complete/)

Comment: Hey, It is working, but when both of the switches are off the LED is a bit lit up,
https://ibb.co/s1sHLk0

Comment: that's just a visual glitch, add an ammeter and you'll see (mine is backward but don't worry about the negative sign, just care about the difference between 0 and 20mA): https://www.tinkercad.com/things/iETIg5v1S6E-mighty-curcan-jaagub/editel?sharecode=lcjcD7BOPJiM8EahqR6YlJryYgVC2l9KGYVVRo5GjM0

Comment: Thanks man, I did it in real life, It is working well

Comment: @Aland out of curiosity what are you going to do with these gates? I once tried building my own 8-bit CPU but it was insanely power-hungry so I gave up on using bare transistors. CMOS would have been better than TTL but hindsight is always 20/20.

Comment: I am still exploring gates but I'll probably make a calculator or an 8-bit CPU, Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Aland if you remove the ground wires in my Tinkercad link, the weird glow comes back, you can report this to Tinkercad since again, this is purely a visual glitch, but the added ground (black) wires help solve it.

Comment: Thanks man, You really helped alot

Comment: @Aland you're welcome. Also if you're trying to build your own CPU, I recommend you watch this series:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyznrdDSSGM&list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU . I don't like his architecture to be honest but it's a very good starting point for beginners. You can also try "Truing complete" which is a game where you design your own CPU.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Aland do you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: @OM222O Thanks looks good

Answer (score 0):

You need three resistors. The first should replace your link from pin 13 to Bat+. This will limit the overall current to the LED when the gate is turned on. I'd suggest about 1K. Then you need a base resistor for each transistor, call it  10k each. This won't work perfectly. When you close S3, the base current will flow through the LED and turn it on, although not as brightly as when both switches are closed.

You are better off with something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fesjBU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that now the base current on the bottom transistor does not flow through the LED.